# two onclick on activity convert into fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to the fragment.

in Activity, I have two onClick methods which are:

1. click that override the method
2. normal onclick

how can I change the onclick that override the method to fragment?

```
private void searchMobileNumber() {
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new SelectExistingOrNewNoFragment.RecyclerTouchListener(PostpaidRegistrationActivity.this, mRecyclerView, new SelectExistingOrNewNoFragment.ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            selectedPostion = position;
            mob_number_detail_lyt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mobile_no_head_lyt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mobile_number_success.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.validation_correct));
            if (simCardFirstTime) {
                simCardFirstTime = false;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(PostpaidRegistrationActivity.this, MyScanActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ocrType", "Barcode");
                intent.putExtra("message", "Please scan your SIM card");
                startActivityForResult(intent, MposConstants.SIMCARD_FIRST_TIME);
            }
}

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Provide more details by Adding Activity.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this clear, you have two buttons. One of which is to start a `fragment` or do something with it.. You just need a `switch` case. Also, use the `R` class for the cases.

Use `view.getId()`

Code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {

     switch(view.getId()){

       case R.id.fragment_button:
             // do something with fragment
             break;
       default: break;
     }
}
```